# PHP Error when trying to execute a prepared statement

Tags: php, database, prepared-statement

I am learning about PHP and recently learned about prepared statements, so I tried modifying a working piece of code I had where I could insert into a database without using prepared statements.

After modifying my code, it seems like I can't make it work, I've followed W3Schools guide but I can't seem to find my mistake, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Also, how can I echo the result of my $stmt so I can display whatever error I have? because `if(!$stmt){echo $stmt->error;}` does not seem to work.

```
<?php    
$servername = "myServer";
$username = "myUsername";
$password = "myPw";
$dbname = "myDB";

$globalID=intval($_GET['globalID']);
$nombreEsposo=$_GET['nombreEsposo'];
$trabajoEsposo=$_GET['nombreEsposa'];
$nombreEsposa=$_GET['trabajoEsposo'];
$trabajoEsposa=$_GET['nombreEsposa'];
$domicilio=$_GET['domicilio'];
$colonia=$_GET['colonia'];
$localidad=$_GET['localidad'];
$telefono=intval($_GET['telefono']);
$miembrosFamilia=intval($_GET['miembrosFamilia']);
$numeroHombres=intval($_GET['numeroHombres']);
$numeroMujeres=intval($_GET['numeroMujeres']);
$numeroEstudiantes=intval($_GET['numeroEstudiantes']);
$miembrosTrabajan=intval($_GET['miembrosTrabajan']);


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO datosfamilia (idReporte,nombreEsposo,trabajoEsposo,nombreEsposa,trabajoEsposa,domicilio,colonia,localidad,telefono,miembrosFamilia,numHombres,numMujeres,numEstudiantes,numTrabajan)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param("isssssssiiiiii",$globalID,$nombreEsposo,$trabajoEsposo,$nombreEsposa,$trabajoEsposa,$domicilio,$colonia,$localidad,$telefono,$miembrosFamilia,$numHombres,$numMujeres,$numeroEstudiantes,$numTrabajan);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$stmt is an object and you cannot perform falsy evaluation on it to test if a query worked.

Print the value of $stmt->error instead.

```
print($stmt->error);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php

Comment: Thank you, problem was I didn't notice I was writing some of my fields wrong on my `bind_param` function. Which echoing the `$stmt` error indeed told me. :D

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this method to test whether your query successfully perform or not.

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
if($result){
   echo 'success';
}else{
   echo 'error';
}
```